# Organizing Mac desktop icons

Tags: macos, desktop-customization

My Mac desktop is a mess, and there's only one piece of software that I envy Windows users for - [Bumptop](http://bumptop.com).

What software would you suggest for Mac desktop organization?

Comment: They are already working on a Mac version of Bumptop - currently it's in Alpha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bumptop for Mac is out and that's what I use now.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to work for everyone, but [here's an idea](http://www.shelterpop.com/2009/10/09/organize-your-desktop-no-not-that-one/) I had never thought of before.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth do you need lots of icons on your Mac desktop?  Put apps/folders that you use often in the dock, and start those you run less frequently by typing the first few letters into Spotlight.  Putting the Applications folder in the dock is also useful for running infrequently used apps.

Answer (score 1):

I find that quicksilver (http://quicksilver.en.softonic.com/mac) is the way to go. Once I installed that I stopped keeping anything on my desktop at all, since all files and folders become instantly available with a few keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on actually organizing the contents of your Desktop folder, there are many "junk drawer" applications out there.

Free:

- [DevonNote](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/devonnote/index.html)

Free-ish:

- [Journler 2.6](http://www.journler.com/) or the last donation-ware version: [2.5.4 beta](http://homepage.mac.com/philipdow/Journler2.5.4beta.zip)

Pay:

- [Voodoo Pad](http://flyingmeat.com/voodoopad/)
- [Yojimbo](http://www.barebones.com/products/yojimbo/)
- [DevonThink Personal/Pro/Office](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/devonthink/)  *I use Pro, myself.  The 2.0 betas are free to use without registering on Personal/Pro.
- [ShoveBox](http://www.wonderwarp.com/shovebox/)